# Adding the app name to a ContentType field in the Django admin change form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django admin site for email templates. 
These email templates have a ContentType ForeignKey field. This field is displayed in the admin change view.

The Model: (Non relevant code not displayed)

```
class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=200, unique=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('Content Type'))
```

The admin.py: (Non relevant code not displayed)

```
class EmailTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EmailTemplateForm
    list_display = ('name',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('monospace',),
            'fields': ('name','content_type',)
        }),
    )
```

I want to customize the field "content_type" now. Right now it just displays the ContentType, I want to add the corresponding "app_label" to it (We have many apps and sadly, some models exist in multiple apps (So the name is shown twice with no way of distinguishing it). This is quite a legacy codebase and renaming all the models to be unique between apps is not possible.

In short:

How do I change my content_types field to display like this: "[Content_type][Content_type.app_label]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own custom field for your `EmailTemplateForm`

```
class EmailTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EmailTemplateForm
    list_display = ('name',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('monospace',),
            'fields': ('name','content_type',)
        }),
    )

class EmailTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content_type = CustomModelChoiceField(queryset=ContentType.objects.all()) 
    class Meta:
          model = EmailTemplate
...

class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         # maybe you can find better solution to get app_label
         return "%s %s" % (obj, obj.__class__._meta.app_label)
```

Comment: Works in part, it simply displays "content_type" behind every actual content_type where it should display "app_name1", "app_name2", etc.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, fixed it. I had to use obj.app_label instead of obj.__class__._meta.app_label.